# Validate javax.validation annotated object throught cxf service

Tags: spring, validation, cxf, jax-ws, bean-validation

I have a sample class like this

```
public class Log implements Serializable{

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9]")
    private String controller;
}
```

and a cxf webservice:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.DOCUMENT, use=Use.LITERAL)
@SchemaValidation
public interface LogService {

    @WebMethod BigInteger createLog(@NotNull String appName,@Valid Log log);
}
```

This is my spring ws configuration:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="logService" implementor="#logServiceEndpoint"
    address="/logService">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>

<bean id="logServiceEndpoint" class="it.trecube.logging.ws.LogServiceImpl">
    <property name="controller" ref="loggingController"></property>
</bean>
```

I would that Log class is validated and that this information are presented into created wsdl and appName validated also, but i try to pass appName=null and Log without controller and all go ok...

i use spring, maven and cxf

tanks for reply and sorry for my bad english